# Change fillcolor after certain time with PaperJS

Tags: paperjs

I am trying to make the fillcolor change back to the original color after a set amount of time.

```
var point = new Point(20, 20);


var newPoint = Point.random() * view.size;
window.position = new Point(newPoint, newPoint);
var newPoint2 = Point.random() * view.size;
window2.position = new Point(newPoint2, newPoint2);
var newPoint3 = Point.random() * view.size;
window3.position = new Point(newPoint3, newPoint3);
var newPoint4 = Point.random() * view.size;
window4.position = new Point(newPoint4, newPoint4);
var newPoint5 = Point.random() * view.size;
window5.position = new Point(newPoint5, newPoint5);
var newPoint6 = Point.random() * view.size;
window6.position = new Point(newPoint6, newPoint6);
var newPoint7 = Point.random() * view.size;
window7.position = new Point(newPoint7, newPoint7);
var newPoint8 = Point.random() * view.size;
window8.position = new Point(newPoint8, newPoint8);
var newPoint9 = Point.random() * view.size;
window9.position = new Point(newPoint9, newPoint9);
var newPoint10 = Point.random() * view.size;
window10.position = new Point(newPoint10, newPoint10);


};


 };






  if(event.delta === 4){
window.fillColor = "coral";
window2.fillColor = "coral";
window3.fillColor = "coral";
window4.fillColor = "coral";
window5.fillColor = "coral";
window6.fillColor = "coral";
window7.fillColor = "coral";
window8.fillColor = "coral";
window9.fillColor = "coral";
window10.fillColor = "coral";
};
```

I know that the event.delta needs to be inside some sort of event handler but if I put it in onFrame the fillcolor sets to coral automatically even though it shouldn't until the time has gone that I've set it too. 
Any ideas how to resolve this problem?

Comment: can you properly indent your code and post a [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/) perhaps?

Comment: Yes, indenting your code would be nice

Comment: Indentation is on it's way.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `event.count`.

UPDATE: [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/dY4xDoMwEAS/Yl0FEuIBTp8PpMQpzHFJEGYvgiMN4u8xVDRsN9odaVdCHIU8PQYx/lBFrN3OrwVsvcIp7lOeFPITWLkGuBxWzJqkTvouAh1V3Umy6ANV7sTl7VpgXWAn4eBd2PKNdpI4fLWHzeSb5/YH).